# Определить направление вращения по трем значениям (C++)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-c++, логика

Существует реальный безупорный галетник (ручка, крутилка), стоящий в кабине самолета, с него при вращении по CAN-шине через плату приема поступает пакет данных. Полезные и необходимые мне данные хранятся в первом байте в первых трех битах. 
Как к ним обратиться и прочее, я знаю, вопрос в том, как определить в какую сторону вращают галетник: по часовой или против.
Грубо говоря, он присылает мне три значения 1, 2, 4, при вращении по часовой они сменяют друг друга при каждом щелке по возрастанию: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4, а против часовой: 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1.

Понимаю, что нужно сравнивать значение в текущем цикле со значением в предыдущем цикле, а переходы от 4 -> 1, 1 -> 4 обрабатывать просто отдельным условием. Но возможно есть более изящное и лаконичное решение для данной задачи, нежели несколько if-else?

Comment: Вместо if else можно использовать case

Comment: ищите в интернете по словам `unwrap phase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно построить конечный автомат на одной таблице, содержащей переходы с учетом предыдущих двух состояний не используя вообще никаких ветвлений. При этом возврат в начальное состояние будет означать что датчик сбоит:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

enum class t_Direction
{
    indeterminate
,   left
,   right
};

struct
t_State final
{
    ::std::array<::std::uint8_t, 8> next_state_indexes;
    t_Direction direction;
};

inline constexpr ::std::array<t_State, 16> const s_lookup
{//          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
    t_State{{0,  1,  2,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 0

,   t_State{{0,  1,  4,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 1   1
,   t_State{{0,  7,  2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 2   2
,   t_State{{0,  8,  9,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 3   4

,   t_State{{0,  7,  2,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 4   1 -> 2
,   t_State{{0,  8,  13, 0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 5   1 -> 4

,   t_State{{0,  11, 9,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 6   2 -> 4
,   t_State{{0,  1,  4,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 7   2 -> 1

,   t_State{{0,  1, 12,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 8   4 -> 1
,   t_State{{0, 14,  2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::indeterminate} // 9   4 -> 2

,   t_State{{0, 11,  9,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::right        } // 10  1 -> 2 -> 4
,   t_State{{0,  1, 12,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::right        } // 11  2 -> 4 -> 1
,   t_State{{0,  7,  2,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::right        } // 12  4 -> 1 -> 2

,   t_State{{0, 14,  2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::left         } // 13  1 -> 4 -> 2
,   t_State{{0,  1,  4,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::left         } // 14  4 -> 2 -> 1
,   t_State{{0,  8, 13,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0}, t_Direction::left         } // 15  2 -> 1 -> 4
};

inline constexpr auto const & operator <<
(
    t_State const & step
,   ::std::uint8_t const input
) noexcept
{
    return s_lookup[step.next_state_indexes[input bitand 0x07]];
}

template
<
    typename... x_Input
>
inline constexpr auto Fold
(
    x_Input const... input
) noexcept
{
    return (s_lookup.front() << ... << input).direction;
}

static_assert(t_Direction::right         == Fold(1, 2, 4));
static_assert(t_Direction::right         == Fold(1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4));
static_assert(t_Direction::right         == Fold(2, 4, 1, 2, 4));
static_assert(t_Direction::left          == Fold(4, 2, 1));
static_assert(t_Direction::left          == Fold(4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1));
static_assert(t_Direction::left          == Fold(2, 1, 4, 2, 1));
static_assert(t_Direction::indeterminate == Fold(1, 2, 1));
static_assert(t_Direction::left          == Fold(1, 2, 1, 4));

int main()
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

"реальный безупорный галетник" - это словосочетание надо будет запомнить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)
Да, формулировка без контекста звучит забавно, просто хотел дать понять, что галетник не сымитирован, а является реальным органом управления в кабине.

Answer (score 2):

Классический конечный автомат. Множество состояний (прошлое значение) совпадает с входным алфавитом (новое значение). Реализуется массивом, где первый индекс - прошлое значение, второй - новое, а значение - результат.